# Sending email in C# using SendGrid with API_KEY

Tags: c#, sendgrid, api-key

I have been using SendGrid to send email from a C# program for years now and it has been excellent using the following code:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
```

With SendGrid requiring API_KEYS they require the following now:
username: "apikey"
password: "API Key"

I'm at a loss though on what to actually do to get the emails sending again.

Is there anyone that can help?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(587)` -- solid code.

Comment: well. there's nothing but read the documentation or download the sample code. I've remember they provide an ApiKey instead of username and password.

Comment: I have now resolved this and will upload the resolution when I get some time.  If anyone needs a solution in the future and I haven't posted mine yet, feel free to message me here.

Comment: I imagine it's an artifact of some prior code that was setting the port via configuration. In which case it may have involved changing the string `"587"` to the integer `587`